# High memory usage in React Native FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, performance, memory-management, react-hooks

I am developing an app which allows the user to search for books and then display it in the search results. For displaying the results, I am using a FlatList with 3 columns and displaying the book cover and some basic information about the book.

I am storing the results from the API response in state without the comoponent. As more results are added, the memory consumption increases but the data is in JSON format, no images are store in state.

I have tried, using `removeClippedSubviews` and few other options that allow setting the window size but that has little to no difference on the memory usage.

Am I missing something here or is there a way to optimise this? Sample code is uploaded to this [github repo](https://github.com/vivekrk/memory-leak-flatlist.git)

Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import type { Node } from 'react';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {
    ActivityIndicator,
    FlatList,
    Platform,
    SafeAreaView,
    StatusBar,
    StyleSheet,
    useColorScheme,
    View,
} from 'react-native';
import { Button, SearchBar, useTheme } from 'react-native-elements';
import { searchBooks } from './api/GoogleBooksService';
import HttpClient from './network/HttpClient';
import BookCard from './components/BookCard';

const searchParamsInitialState = {
    startIndex: 1,
    maxResults: 12,
    totalItems: null,
};

let debounceTimer;
const debounce = (callback, time) => {
    clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
    debounceTimer = setTimeout(callback, time);
};

const isEndOfList = searchParams => {
    const { startIndex, maxResults, totalItems } = searchParams;
    if (totalItems == null) {
        return false;
    }
    console.log('isEndOfList', totalItems - (startIndex - 1 + maxResults) < 0);
    return totalItems - (startIndex - 1 + maxResults) < 0;
};

const App: () => Node = () => {
    const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
    const [globalSearchResults, setGlobalSearchResults] = useState([]);
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useState(searchParamsInitialState);

    let searchCancelToken;
    let searchCancelTokenSource;

    // This ref will be used to track if the search Term has changed when tab is switched
    const searchRef = useRef();

    const clearSearch = () => {
        console.log('Clear everything!');
        searchRef.current = null;
        setGlobalSearchResults([]);
        setSearchParams(searchParamsInitialState);
        setIsLoading(false);
        searchCancelTokenSource?.cancel();
        searchCancelToken = null;
        searchCancelTokenSource = null;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        debounce(async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            await searchGlobal(searchTerm);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }, 1000);
    }, [searchTerm]);

    /**
     * Search method
     */
    const searchGlobal = async text => {
        if (!text) {
            // Clear everything
            clearSearch();
            return;
        }
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            // Use the initial state values if the search term has changed
            let params = searchParams;
            if (searchRef.current !== searchTerm) {
                params = searchParamsInitialState;
            }

            const { items, totalItems } = await searchBooks(
                text,
                params.startIndex,
                params.maxResults,
                searchCancelTokenSource?.token,
            );
            if (searchRef.current === searchTerm) {
                console.log('Search term has not changed. Appending data');
                setGlobalSearchResults(prevState => prevState.concat(items));
                setSearchParams(prevState => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    startIndex: prevState.startIndex + prevState.maxResults,
                    totalItems,
                }));
            } else {
                console.log(
                    'Search term has changed. Updating data',
                    searchTerm,
                );
                if (!searchTerm) {
                    console.log('!searchTerm', searchTerm);
                    clearSearch();
                    return;
                }
                setGlobalSearchResults(items);
                setSearchParams({
                    ...searchParamsInitialState,
                    startIndex:
                        searchParamsInitialState.startIndex +
                        searchParamsInitialState.maxResults,
                    totalItems,
                });
            }
            searchRef.current = text;
        } catch (err) {
            if (HttpClient.isCancel(err)) {
                console.error('Cancelled', err.message);
            }
            console.error(`Error searching for "${text}"`, err);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
    };

    const renderGlobalItems = ({ item }) => {
        return <BookCard book={item} />;
    };

    const { theme } = useTheme();

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.backgroundStyle}>
            <StatusBar
                barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
            />
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <SearchBar
                    showLoading={isLoading}
                    placeholder="Enter search term here"
                    onChangeText={text => {
                        setSearchTerm(text);
                    }}
                    value={searchTerm}
                    platform={Platform.OS}
                />
                {isLoading && globalSearchResults.length <= 0 && (
                    <ActivityIndicator animating style={styles.loader} />
                )}
                {globalSearchResults.length > 0 && (
                    <FlatList
                        removeClippedSubviews
                        columnWrapperStyle={styles.columnWrapper}
                        data={globalSearchResults}
                        numColumns={3}
                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                        keyExtractor={item => item + item.id}
                        renderItem={renderGlobalItems}
                        ListFooterComponent={
                            <>
                                {!isLoading &&
                                    !isEndOfList(searchParams) &&
                                    searchParams.totalItems > 0 && (
                                        <Button
                                            type="clear"
                                            title="Load more..."
                                            onPress={async () => {
                                                await searchGlobal(searchTerm);
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    )}
                                {isLoading && searchParams.totalItems != null && (
                                    <ActivityIndicator
                                        size="large"
                                        style={{
                                            justifyContent: 'center',
                                        }}
                                        color={theme.colors.primary}
                                    />
                                )}
                            </>
                        }
                    />
                )}
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    backgroundStyle: 'white',
    container: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
    },
    columnWrapper: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    loader: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) in react native. If you create FlatList as PureComponent, you can see lot of improvement.

It will not rerender items until data has been changed.

for example:

```
class MyList extends React.PureComponent {

}
```

For more reference [check this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13649#issuecomment-296987773)

Comment: Thanks. But this is for Stateful components, I am using stateless functional components. The closest to PureComponent for this is [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) which I tried but did not make much of a difference

Comment: As per my understanding, PureComponents will improve drawing performance. not sure if it will effect memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to chuck your array of list items into small sub-arrays, this package uses this mechanism https://github.com/bolan9999/react-native-largelist

The package has been praised by complex app teams including the Discord Mobile Team - https://discord.com/blog/how-discord-achieves-native-ios-performance-with-react-native